# Change output of cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am an Excel and Xpath noob (well, at least I am honest!). I am working on a project that, at present, I have got working through learning from online tutorials. However, the next step has me stumped!

I am hosting a document on Google Sheets and as such, want to try and avoid VBA (which I have no idea about yet, anyway.....) and hope I can multi function/formula in one cell instead.

I am using Xpath to populate a cell with an input from an XML document. The function is:

**=ImportXML("https://api.eveonline.com/corp/StarbaseList.xml.aspx?keyID=*******&vCode=***********","//row[@itemID='*******']/@state")**

There are only two possible cell outputs from this function - "1" or "4" and currently have this working fine.

However, I require to change the cell display from "1" to "**OFFLINE**" in red text, and "4" to "**ONLINE**" in green text, but do not even know where to begin doing this.......

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `=IF(ComparisonHere = 1, "OFFLINE", "ONLINE")` ?

In context - `=IF(ImportXML("https://api.eveonline.com/corp/StarbaseList.xml.aspx?keyID=*******&vCode=***********","//row[@itemID='*******']/@state") = "1", "OFFLINE", "ONLINE")` - then use `conditional formatting` to change the colours. Only because you're certain there are only two outputs, if a 2 or 3 could be output you'll need a condition check to be sure it's returned a 4.

Comment: Easy when you know how! You are a true gent.....works as I need it to. HUGE thanks :)

Comment: No problem. Just to help you understand if there's any confusion, the formula is:  =IF(Comparison, True, False). So, the first argument is what you're comparing (EG - Cell A1 > 1, Cell A2 = "Test"). The next argument is what the output will be if the result is true, the final argument is the result if false.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I'm posting this wiki so that it will have an answer and can be closed. All information is straight from the comments made by @Jonno</sub>

---

`=IF(ComparisonHere = 1, "OFFLINE", "ONLINE")`

In context:

```
=IF(ImportXML("https://api.eveonline.com/corp/StarbaseList.xml.aspx?keyID=*******&vCo‌​de=***********","//row[@itemID='*******']/@state") = "1", "OFFLINE", "ONLINE")
```

Use conditional formatting to change the colours. This only works because you're certain there are only two outputs. If the output could be a 2 or 3, you'll need a condition check to be sure it's returned a 4.

Just to help you understand if there's any confusion, the formula is `=IF(Comparison, True, False)`. So, the first argument is what you're comparing (EG - Cell A1 > 1, Cell A2 = "Test"). The next argument is what the output will be if the result is true, the final argument is the result if false.